# Windows Server 2012 DNS – how to create DNS policies

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, configuration

I have an Window Server 2012 R2 DNS server , Active Directory integrated, deserving 3 different internal networks , in a single domain.

I need to make it responding to DNS queries  based on client IP address.

This means that for “mycomputer” hostname, clients from each network would receive an different IP address (inside their network) ,from the DNS Server .

I have seen that this mechanism is implemented in Windows Server 2016 as described here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/primary-geo-location

But in windows Server 2012 R2, how can this be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the DNS return the same results for rhe same questions ... but with multiple A records . The clients will prefer the A record there the address is on the same net as their own.

Dont break DNS by forcing the daemon to consider who made the query (or separate Dns servers)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know I can do this...I will try and come back with feedback...

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The DNS Policies feature was introduced with Windows Server 2016. It isn't available in Windows Server 2012 nor in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know this!